# What could I do to stop this scammer?

Tags: united-states, california, fraud, vehicle, identity-theft

I saw on Craigslist a car that used to belong to me for sale with a lower mileage than it had when I sold it (by more than 200000 miles). I want to stop this person from causing any damage, but I contacted police and they say that this is a civil case that should be brought by the future victim of this fraud (they lied though, this is a felony under federal law). I contacted DMV and they say that they will investigate about one month after a formal complaint is filed. In one month the car will be likely to be sold already and the suspect will probably be much harder to track. The DMV informed me that the car still is in my name, although they received already the Declaration of Release of Liability. It does not stop the suspect to be selling using my name and the possible victim filing a lawsuit against me, burdening me with the legal process. I checked the address given by the buyer and noticed that it does not exist, so I assume that the name he gave also is fake. How could I have the suspect stopped before anyone fall victim of this crime?

Comment: It's a federal crime, so you've reported it to federal law enforcement, right? Of course the local police aren't interested - they can't do enough to make the coat worthwhile.

Comment: If it's a federal crime, try calling the FBI field office.